# Load contents of alexa php results with parameters into html page - Maybe using jquery or ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, api, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to load the alexa rank of a website as a piece of text into a standard html file.  I want to avoid setting up the whole page as php so I've created a php file called rank.php which works

```
<?php
$url=$_GET["url"];
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url='.$url);
$rank=isset($xml->SD[1]->POPULARITY)?$xml->SD[1]->POPULARITY->attributes()->TEXT:0;
echo $rank;
?>
```

I can load this to my server and call it with something like rank.php?url=google.com

This returns a number on the screen (in this case 1). So how do I get that number into a normal `<p>` tag in a html document.

Ie `<p>Alex rank: </p>`

I'm looking into jquery and using the get method but I'm getting lost.

eg putting this in the `<head></head>` tags

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#div1").load("code/rank.php?url=google.com");
});
</script>
```

Then in my html page adding

`<p>Alex rank: <div id="div1"></div></p>`

doesn't work for me.

I've also tried adding the following script within the `<p></p>` tag.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
       function showGetResult( name )
{
 jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'code/rank.php?url=google.com',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'text/html',
    success:function(data)
    {
        alert(data);
        document.write(data);
        } 
     });
}

showGetResult('test');
</script>
```

I just want a simple solution to pull that number across.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'code/rank.php?url=google.com',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'text/html',
    success:function(data)
    {
        alert(data);
        document.write(data);
        } 
 });
```

I made some tests - and it seems that this is a culprit:
**dataType: 'text/html'**

Why:
in documentation of jQuery - at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

dataType allowed values:

- "xml"
- "html"
- "json"
- "jsonp"
- "text"
- multiple, space-separated values

I tried
**dataType: 'text'**

Worked for me.

Be sure to put your script tag after

if you are executing it inline of your page

```
<p>Alexa rank: <span id="div-1"></span></p>

<script>
 jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'code/rank.php?url=google.com',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'text',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data)
    {
        alert(data);

        // comment: $('#div-1').html(data)
        // inserts data inside $('#div-1')
        $('#div-1').html(data);
    } 
 });
</script>
```

But cleaner way to do it:

```
<html>
<head>
   <script>

   // comment:
   //     in jQuery
   //         $( yourFunction )
   //     is a shortcut for
   //         $(document).ready( yourFunction )
   $(function(){
      jQuery.ajax({
          url: 'code/rank.php?url=google.com',
          type: 'get',
          dataType: 'text',
          cache: false,
          success: function(data)
          {
              alert(data);

              // comment: $('#div-1').html(data)
              // inserts data inside $('#div-1')
              $('#div-1').html(data);
          } 
       });
   });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <p>Alexa rank: <span id="div-1"></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

In this last code I am using **cache: false** because I feel it is good for this case. I am using **dataType: 'text'** because you are expecting just a number - so why not? It just fells more KISS for me. Perhaps it will work with **'html'**.

By the way - there can be another place where another mistake can be hidden:
code/rank.php?url=google.com

If you current URL is
www.example.com/somefolder/
then it will be interpreted as
www.example.com**/somefolder/**code/rank.php?url=google.com

If your current URL is www.example.com/somefolder/another/
then it will be interpreted as
www.example.com**/somefolder/another/**code/rank.php?url=google.com

My advise - you can always use Firefox or Google Chrome Developer Tools > Network to see what is returning your ajax request - a '1' or 'PAGE 404 NOT FOUND' ^_^
     jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'code/rank.php?url=google.com',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'text/html',
        success:function(data)
        {
            alert(data);
            document.write(data);
            } 
     });

I made some tests - and it seems that this is a culprit:
**dataType: 'text/html'**

Why:
in documentation of jQuery - at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

dataType allowed values:

- "xml"
- "html"
- "json"
- "jsonp"
- "text"
- multiple, space-separated values

I tried
**dataType: 'text'**

Worked for me.

Be sure to put your script tag after

if you are executing it inline of your page

```
<p>Alexa rank: <span id="div-1"></span></p>

<script>
 jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'code/rank.php?url=google.com',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'text',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data)
    {
        alert(data);

        // comment: $('#div-1').html(data)
        // inserts data inside $('#div-1')
        $('#div-1').html(data);
    } 
 });
</script>
```

But cleaner way to do it:

```
<html>
<head>
   <script>

   // comment:
   //     in jQuery
   //         $( yourFunction )
   //     is a shortcut for
   //         $(document).ready( yourFunction )
   $(function(){
      jQuery.ajax({
          url: 'code/rank.php?url=google.com',
          type: 'get',
          dataType: 'text',
          cache: false,
          success: function(data)
          {
              alert(data);

              // comment: $('#div-1').html(data)
              // inserts data inside $('#div-1')
              $('#div-1').html(data);
          } 
       });
   });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <p>Alexa rank: <span id="div-1"></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

In this last code I am using **cache: false** because I feel it is good for this case. I am using **dataType: 'text'** because you are expecting just a number - so why not? It just fells more KISS for me. Perhaps it will work with **'html'**.

By the way - there can be another place where another mistake can be hidden:
code/rank.php?url=google.com

If you current URL is
www.example.com/somefolder/
then it will be interpreted as
www.example.com**/somefolder/**code/rank.php?url=google.com

If your current URL is www.example.com/somefolder/another/
then it will be interpreted as
www.example.com**/somefolder/another/**code/rank.php?url=google.com

My advise - you can always use Firefox or Google Chrome Developer Tools > Network to see what is returning your ajax request - a '1' or 'PAGE 404 NOT FOUND' ^_^

### Answering comment:

Yes, you've got the gist of it right.
Here is one way how you could implement it
(it would be comfortable for my way of thinking and organizing code):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    // defining tool:
    function updateRankForSite( inUrl, $inInsertTo ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'code/rank.php?url=' + inUrl,
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'text',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
                $inInsertTo.html(data);
            } 
        });
    }
    </script>
    <script>

    // using tool:
    $(function(){
        outputRankForSite( 'google.com', $('#rank-google') );
        outputRankForSite( 'yandex.com', $('#rank-yandex') );

        // and here is example how to interact with user
        $('button-1').click( function( event ) {

            // comment
            // event.preventDefault() blocks default behavior
            // for clicking on <a href="...">...</a> tag
            // that means you wouldn'd be redirected to href
            event.preventDefault();
            outputRankForSite(
                'stackoverflow.com',
                $('#rank-stackoverflow')
            );

            // comment:
            // and you can leverage not just 'stackoverflow.com'
            // but anything that user wants - he can
            // put his request to <input="text" id="example-input" ...>
            // and you could collect his input by using command like
            // $('#example-input').val()
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Alexa rank for google.com: <span id="rank-google"></span></p>
    <p>Alexa rank for yandex.com: <span id="rank-yandex"></span></p>
    <p>
        Alexa rank for stackoverflow.com (press button to get rank):
        <span id="rank-stackoverflow"></span>
    </p>
    <a href="#" id="button-1">Press this button to update rank</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks.  I may have had a few errors in there but the Developer Tools > Network put me on the right track.  I'm doing a redesign of my live site and don't want to load anything to the server yet but I had to to get the php aspect working.  I had a local copy of jQuery and like an idiot I hadn't loaded it to the server.  All working now thanks.

Comment: I have a follow up question. Is there a way to extend to to any url by passing a value to the function.   Something like.                                                               `<script>

   $(function(arg){
      jQuery.ajax({
          url: 'code/rank.php?url='+arg.url,
          type: 'get',
          dataType: 'text',
          cache: false,
          success: function(data)
          {
                         // comment: $('#div-1').html(data)
              // inserts data inside $('#div-1')
              $('#arg.div').html(data);
          } 
       });
   });
   </script>`

Comment: I added "Answering comment:" to the answer.